# Can I have a separate realm for mobile app and separate realm for web app opened through laptop/desktop

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openam, forgerock

I want to create 2 realm with separate grant types for each.  One for mobile application opened using the mobile phones.  And the other for web applications used by laptop/desktop.  Is there a possibility to provide the authentication URL based on identifying the mobile or laptop/desktop.  Accordingly I would like to configure one realm for mobile and the other for laptop/desktop.  If any one has tried the same or has some possibility/idea request to share the same.

If any suggestion on help on the same, it would be useful.

thanks
Lokesh

Comment: Well, in OAuth 2.0 there is no concept of a "realm". You can certainly create two different Client IDs (one for mobile and one for "Web" based.) Not sure what you imply by "authentication URL" as the "authentication URL" is determined by the Authorization server. Some Authorization server implementations do create dynamic authentication URLs for each client.

Comment: Realms are meant to differentiate user bases, not client types. Can you describe your use-case for having separate realms for the different client types?

Answer (score 0):

you can create two user group and two different policy one for mobile and desktop/web. Assign permission accordingly.